# error TS7031/TS7006/TS2339: Binding element 'dispatch'/ 'next' / 'action' / 'checked' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I cloned an react spfx app from github. Because I cannot build it because of old depricated modules I try to build a new solution from scratch. Now I stuck with the error:

Binding element 'X' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Why do I get this error and how to fix it?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.module.scss';
import type { ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps } from './ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps';
import "../assets/webchat.js";

export default class SpfxTestKhhaWebpart extends React.Component<ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps> {
    const styleOptions = {
      // Add styleOptions to customize web chat canvas
      hideUploadButton: true
    };

    const theURL = "https://powerva.microsoft.com/api/botmanagement/v1/directline/directlinetoken?botId=" + this.props.botid;

    const store = (window as any).WebChat.createStore(
      {},
      ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === "DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED") {
          dispatch({
            meta: {
              method: "keyboard",
            },
            payload: {
              activity: {
                channelData: {
                  postBack: true,
                },
                //Web Chat will show the 'Greeting' System Topic message which has a trigger-phrase 'hello'
                name: 'startConversation',
                type: "event"
              },
            },
            type: "DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY",
          });
        }
        return next(action);
      }
    );
    fetch(theURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(conversationInfo => {
        (window as any).WebChat.renderWebChat(
          {
            directLine: (window as any).WebChat.createDirectLine({
              token: conversationInfo.token,
            }),
            store: store,
            styleOptions: styleOptions
          },
          document.getElementById('webchat')
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.error("An error occurred: " + err));

    return (

      <div className={styles.spfxTestKhhaWebpart}>

        {(this.state.checked) ?
          (
            <div className={styles.container}>
              <div className={styles.row}>
                <div className={styles.header} id="header">
                  <div className={styles.header_content_container}>
                    <div className={styles.header_image_container}>
                      <img className={styles.header_image} src={this.props.botlogo} />
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.header_title_container}>
                      <div className={styles.header_title}>
                        <span className={styles.title_text}>{this.props.botname}</span>
                        <span className={styles.close} onClick={() => { this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }) }}>x</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.webchat} id="webchat" role="main"></div>
              </div></div>)
          : (
            <div className={styles.botimage_container}>
              <div className={styles.chatbot_image}>
                <img src={this.props.botimage} style={{ maxHeight: 150 }} onClick={() => { this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }) }} />
              </div>
            </div>)
        }
      </div >
    );
  }
}
```

Versions:

spfx-test-khha@0.0.1 C:\SPFX\test2
├── @fluentui/react@8.112.8
├── @microsoft/eslint-config-spfx@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7@0.1.0
├── @microsoft/sp-build-web@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-component-base@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-core-library@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-lodash-subset@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-module-interfaces@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-property-pane@1.18.1
├── @microsoft/sp-webpart-base@1.18.1
├── @rushstack/eslint-config@2.5.1
├── @types/react-dom@17.0.17
├── @types/react@17.0.45
├── @types/webpack-env@1.15.3
├── ajv@6.12.6
├── bindings@1.5.0 extraneous
├── eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.3.0
├── eslint@8.7.0
├── file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 extraneous
├── gulp@4.0.2
├── nan@2.18.0 extraneous
├── react-dom@17.0.1
├── react@17.0.1
├── tslib@2.3.1
└── typescript@4.7.4

**Error in VS Code:**

[12:14:42] [tsc] typescript version: 4.7.4
[12:14:43] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 2.12 s
[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(25,10): error TS7031: Binding element 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type.
[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(25,25): error TS7006: Parameter 'next' implicitly has an 'any' type.[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(25,33): error TS7006: Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.
[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(67,22): error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(79,110): error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
[12:14:53] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/spfxTestKhhaWebpart/components/SpfxTestKhhaWebpart.tsx(89,129): error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
[12:14:53] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 11 s
exited with code 2
[12:14:53] 'build' errored after 14 s
[12:14:53]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

**Update** I already found a workaround to overrule tslint.config with

"noImplicitAny": false

But I still would like to know how I can fix it without the tslint rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config of `noImplicitAny`, actually refers to the fallback TypeScript uses when there are no type annotations. This setting typically enables and disables whether TypeScript will throw `error` on fallbacks. You can check this in their [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).

In other words, even if you declare a variable with `any` type (e.g., `dispatch: any`), the error will immediately disappear as you have **explicitly** set it to `any`.

Of course, you would always prefer to define the type as anything other than `any`, as it in some sense hinders the original intentions of using `TypeScript`, which is being `type-safe`.

---

Let's talk about the code. There are two main problems in the question indeed, namely `TS7031/TS3006` and `TS2339`.

The second one is easier to solve. The problem is that you have extended the type of `SpfxTestKhhaWebpart` to `React.Component<ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps, {}>`, and `{}` is a read-only type, which is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html?):

> Tuples tend to be created and left un-modified in most code, so annotating types as readonly tuples when possible is a good default. This is also important given that array literals with const assertions will be inferred with readonly tuple types.

Referencing the [Microsoft TypeScript-React Conversion Guide](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide), the second error should disappear if you set the type to `React.Component<ISpfxTestKhhaWebpartProps, any>`, which enables the use of calling the `state` from this specific `React.Component` typed class.

---

The first one is more tricky, as you would have to set a correct type for all three variables: `dispatch`, `next`, and `action`, which would be hard for me to provide directly as I do not have the environment and cannot conduct test runs (most of the time by simply hover on or using `console.log([target].constructor.name);` could check the needed type).

However, I most certainly believe this part:

```
({ dispatch }) => next => action => {[code_within]})
```

Is, in fact, custom `middleware` configurations from libraries like `redux`, so you could check the parameters and return types of each original function - this [middleware](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware#attempt-5-removing-monkeypatching) guide of `redux` could be a great start (assume you are using `redux`).

That is all I could have thought of, but anyway a good question. Let me know if I could be of further assistance.